# Drupal on IIS: "default" folder permissions issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've an issue with Drupal on an IIS 7 web server.

For some reason I get this error message in the status report. The default folder has only "View" permissions, while the children folder "files" and all subfolders have both write and read: http://d.pr/WZ0F

> Configuration file    Not protected The
>   directory sites/default is not
>   protected from modifications and poses
>   a security risk. You must change the
>   directory's permissions to be
>   non-writable. The file
>   sites/default/settings.php is not
>   protected from modifications and poses
>   a security risk. You must change the
>   file's permissions to be non-writable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this on community [somewhere](http://drupal.org/node/287276)

```
go to DOS,
cd to the site folder
input: attrib +R default
```

or try turning off `register_globals` in php.ini to stop this message.
 but ALL THIS ONLY for IIS6

[THIS MIGHT HELP FOR IIS7](http://drupal.org/node/287276#comment-1542920)

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. Yeah, it is IIS7 indeed. So I can just ignore the error message ?

Comment: @Patrick: u can safely ignore it.or you can modify the core for IIS7. i think they resolved this in Drupal 7 though.